# Cannot start docker on mac - Fatal Error - The operation couldn't be completed. (Docker.VmnetdError error 1.)

Tags: macos, docker

When I installing the docker for Mac, **I got the Fatal Error - The operation couldn't be completed. (Docker.VmnetdError error 1.)** [image]

Answer (score 9):

That issue came because of the, image file directly opening. you can drag the docker image and drop in to the **Applications** and after that open the **Docker.app** from the **Applications** folder. Solves the issue

[image]

Comment: It doesn't solve the issue. Can you please elaborate the reasoning for this solution?

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue. I've filed the same issue at https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6762

Answer (score 1):

Restarting laptop fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

My `Docker.app` was already in the Applications folder but I still got the error `The operation couldn't be completed. (Docker.VmnetdError error 1.)` when trying to open it. What solved it for me was resetting docker by clicking the `Reset Docker to factory defaults`.

Comment: I try "Reset Docker to factory defaults" still not working, I keep getting this error. This is happen after upgrade to macos Ventura.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue for weeks, upgrading to [Version 3.0.0](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/release-notes/#docker-desktop-300) resolved this issue. I
downloaded it and it opens straight away no errors.

[Another error i was seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUKQP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Activity Monitor, search for "docker," and select all the docker related processes, force quit all of them. MacOS will restart the docker